# Excel advanced filter with exclusion

Tags: excel, filter

I have rows like
Username

```
user@example.com
partner.someone@example.com   <== I want to exclude this.
john@example.com
tom@example.com
```

I can define a criterion partner and it filters correctly.

However I want exclude rows containing partner. I have tried following and it is not excluding those rows. I have also tried removing stars around it.

```
Username     
<>*partner*
```

Comment: I've tried to use a text filter and it works. What problem are you encountering?

Comment: Yes, text filter worked. Is advanced filter depricated ?, I couldnot see it in office 365.

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey problem is advanced filter could not filter negation criterion correctly as described in OP

Comment: So is the problem solved?

Comment: You've not given much info - VBA filter (guess not, no VBA tag), Filter button or Filter formula (you've got 365 by the comments)..... with your list in A1:A4 this will ignore partner.someone:  `=FILTER($A$1:$A$4,$A$1:$A$4<>"partner.someone@example.com")`

Comment: Excluding anything with `partner` in it:  `=FILTER($A$1:$A$4,IFERROR(SEARCH("partner",$A$1:$A$4),"")="")`

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook - thanks, it woks !!

Answer (score 0):

## Advanced filter

I defined the following range names:

- af01_source: `=Table1!$B$4:$B$8`
- af01_criteria: `=Table1!$D$4:$D$5`
- af01_target: `=Table1!$F$4`

Opened the Advanced Filter included the range names in the corresponding fields, hit okay and received the following output:

[image]

I recorded this action with the macro recorder and received the following code (after some cosmetic changes):

```
Sub run_af()
    Range("af_source").AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Range("af_criteria"), _
        CopyToRange:=Range("af_target"), _
        Unique:=False
End Sub
```

As you can see, the Advanced Filter is capable of doing the negation you desire.

Did you try it with your shortened example?
Or did you face problems while trying to filter for multiple criteria?

*By the way*

The negation is done in the same way, as the Autofilter / Textfilter would do it:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$4:$B$8").AutoFilter _
      Field:=1, _
      Criteria1:= "<>*partner*", _
      Operator:=xlAnd
```

Answer (score 0):

Why Don't you use a Helper Column

i.e
Your Data is in Column A assuming A1 is 1st Cell of Data

Do it in B1

```
=IF(A1="","",IFERROR(SEARCH("partner",A1),2))
```

In C1 Use Filter

```
=FILTER(A1:A10,B1:B10=2,"")
```